# mysql_fetch_object on complex objects

Tags: php, mysql

Say for example I have the follwoing DB structure

```
Table: book
    id | title | ...

Table: author
    id | name | ...

Table: bookAuthor
    id | bookid | authorid
```

And in PHP I have the following object

```
class Book {
  var $id;
  var $title;
  var $authors = array();

  function Book() {}
}

class Author {
  var $id;
  var $name;

  function Author(){}
}
```

Now, would it be possible **using mysqli_fetch_object** to retrieve the bookobject including the authors as an array of author objects?

If it's possible I'm pretty sure you'll need the basic inner join query

```
SELECT * FROM tblbook INNER JOIN tblbookauthor on ... (wel you get the point)
```

Is it possible?

thanks!

Comment: I might have found a dirty solution: in the constructor of book you could perform a new query to fetch all the authors, and use mysql_fetch_object again. However, I do not want SQL, or links to my data access layer in my model, so this isn't really an option... Plus I don't want to increase the amount of queries, I would like it to be possible with a single query

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is some sort of Active Record system. It is beyond PHP's normal scope, but third party implementations of this kind of functionality exists. Take for example a look at: [AdoDB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Thanks, after some searching I found MyActiveRecord. It's quite old (I think the last update was somewhere in 2007), and for MySql solely... BUT it's incredibly lightweight (which indeed also means there's no tons of extras in it) and ever so flexible. It's exactly what I was looking for!

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2990-PHP-Map-objects-to-MySQL-database-table-rows.html